# pass authentication parameter in webservice

Tags: json, web-services, authentication, header

I am building a webservice server side. In my webservice, every client needs to pass their authentication parameter, via POST method in json format, for every request they make. Is passing parameter via post a good practice?

A guy told me, I should always use GET method to retrieve data; POST should be used for insertion only. If this is so, how am I going to pass the authentication param? One could be through URL and the other through header value. Which way should I use?

Answer (score 0):

try to implement this web service. This web service permits to pass their authentication parameter through header value.

```
@WebService(serviceName="authentication")
public class WSAuthentication {
String name = null;
String password = null;

public WSAuthentication() {
   super();
}

public WSAuthentication(String name, String password) {
   this.name = name;
   this.password = password;
}

private static String getData(WSAuthentication sec) {
   System.out.println("********************* AUTHENTICATION ********************" + "\n" + 
   "**********USER: " + sec.name + "\n" + 
   "******PASSWORD: " + sec.password + "\n" + 
   "******************************** AUTHENTICATION ****************************");
   return sec.name + " -- " + sec.password;
}

@WebMethod(operationName="security", action="authenticate")
@WebResult(name="answer")
public String security(@WebParam(header=true, mode=Mode.IN, name="user") String user, @WebParam(header=true, mode=Mode.IN, name="password") String password) {
    WSAuthentication secure = new WSAuthentication(user, password);
    return getData(secure);
 }
}
```

And I use POST method for response. I hope help you.

Comment: How do you pass value from client side? I am using jersey
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
webResource.header('user','adgsege');
is this way ok?